# How to delete/replace from first space till any english character - VIM

Tags: vim

I have a text file that has Japanese and English characters

```
母音  ぼいん vowel   
子音  しいん consonant   
対話型 たいわがた   interactive 
基本形, 基本型    きほんけい, きほんがた    fundamental form, basic form, basic pattern, basic model, basic type, prototype 
能動態 のうどうたい  active voice    
受動態 じゅどうたい  passive voice
```

How can I delete/replace everything after first space till any english character?

Result:

```
母音,vowel    
子音,consonant    
対話型,interactive 
基本形,fundamental form, basic form, basic pattern, basic model, basic type, prototype 
能動態,active voice    
受動態,passive voice
```

Comment: Thank you guys very much  for your help, Kent & Amadan thank you for your help. I tried your code - but still get some weird spaces, so I have chosen Sato Katsura's answer. Again, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
:%s/\m\s[^a-zA-Z]\{-}\ze[a-zA-Z]/,/
```

Answer (score 4):

try this command:

```
%s/ [^a-zA-Z]*\ze/,/
```

#### update, add some explanation:

Two key points of this command are:

- `\ze` `:h \ze` for detail
- the usage of regex greedy

so basically, the line does the thing described in question title: find the first SPACE, (postion X), and the the first english letter after the SPACE (Position Y), replace `X-Y` by `,`.

`*` in regex is greedy, so `(SPACE)[^a-zA-Z]*` will locate the part of text we want to replace.

Comment: This is more appropriate as just a comment on the question. Perhaps if you took time to explain this suggestion.

Comment: @thecoshman if you want the explanation, you can just ask for it. But I don't agree that this should be a comment. it provided the working solution. If this should be comment, the accepted answer should be comment too. I don't think my answer deserves downvote, unless it is a wrong answer.

Comment: You're answer came up in the review queue. It is not a good answer, simply stating one of line of code that might solve the problem has never been accepted as a good answer on SO.

Comment: @thecoshman ok explanation added. personally I think my cmd is better than the accepted one. E.g. the unnecessary `\m`, `\ze and \{-}`

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s/ .\{-}[a-zA-Z0-9]\@=/,/
```

(replace space and any non-greedy number of characters up to the point where an alphanumeric would follow with a comma)

(using `set magic`)

EDIT: As Kent says, the `g` flag should not be there.

Comment: `g` flag should not be there.